# How to give link to an image in .cs page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, hyperlink

I have a table. In that i have an image and a label. I have to give hyperlink to both of them. I have given hyperlink to label as same i have to give it to the image from the aspx.cs page. Can anyone tell me how to give it???
Plz..
Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question what you are trying to do?
DO you want to just have both the image and the label be clickable, and go to the same url?

You can wrap them in an anchor like so:

```
<a href="[Your url]">
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label Text">

        </asp:Label>
        <img  />
</a>
```